# Rigged Cloth, Collision not working

Tags: rigging, collision

I have created three cloths using bones and none of them will collide. Self Collide is on and the torso part does have collision physic enabled and I have played around with the sliders to no avail. https://gyazo.com/576e08a47ae8429f68732fb9f5d54a3d (GIF showing one of the three cloth's not colliding with object).